# php + sqllite3: Error by prepered update binding, when using IS NULL/ IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, sqlite

So I have to use a prepared statement, otherwise there will be other errors.

I don't know why, but it wasn't possible to prepare two update statements at the same time like this:

```
$sql_update_users =<<<EOF
  UPDATE users SET username = :username, full_name = :full_name, is_private = :is_private , is_following = 3 , updated_on = :time WHERE user_id = :usernameId;

  UPDATE users SET following_on = IfNull(following_on, :time) WHERE user_id = :usernameId;
EOF;

//Datei für update preparen
$smt2 = $db->prepare($sql_update_users);

//bindings...
//execute...
```

^would not work.... :(

so I had to sepperate them:

```
 //preper update
 $smt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET following_on = :time WHERE user_id = :usernameId, following_on IS NULL");

$smt2->bindParam(':usernameId', $usernameId);
$smt2->bindParam(':time', $time);

$smt2->execute();
```

^This will throw an error. I already replaced the "AND" with "," because, that was also a Problem.

> Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean

However, this works:

```
$smt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET following_on = IfNull(following_on, :time) WHERE user_id = :usernameId");
```

^This works.
The Problem is, now I have to update a column, if there are multiple entrys in the row NULL and NOT NULL. And since i get the Error when using "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL", I don't know, what to do.

**EDIT1**

So I remember know, why "AND" won't work. so this line won't work (no error, just doing nothing):

```
UPDATE users SET was_follower = :sync_id AND unfollowed_me_on = :time
```

This line will work:

```
UPDATE users SET was_follower = :sync_id, unfollowed_me_on = :time
```

So i need a solution, to make "AND" work, or a solution to use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL with ","

Comment: `prepare` returns `false` when there is an error. And the error is the comma. Why did you remove the AND?

Comment: @CL. I remember why "AND" won't work. see my EDIT1 please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE users SET following_on = :time WHERE user_id = :usernameId, following_on IS NULL
```

In this query, the comma must be an AND.

```sql
UPDATE users SET was_follower = :sync_id AND unfollowed_me_on = :time
```

In this query, the AND must be a comma (if you want to change `unfollowed_me_on`) or WHERE (if `unfollowed_me_on` determines which rows are to be updated).

Comment: thank you so much, I don't know why, but it's working know :D